# Uncaught ReferenceError : JQuery is not defined

Tags: kendo-grid

I am using **Kendo UI Grid (Inline Editing) for MVC**. I am not getting any result set in the view.
It shows:

> Uncaught ReferenceError : JQuery is not defined.

Can someone advise on this.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna check if you have referenced jquery incorrectly or repeatly

You may wanna refer to

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/troubleshooting

or

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/troubleshooting